# Installing django on two existing versions on python

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have both python 2.7 and 3.2 installed on my computer and I wanted to install django. And when I did it automatically installed django 1.4 on python 3. Is there a way I can install it on python 2.7?

Comment: You didn't mention what OS you are using.

Comment: Or how you installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here is that you should be using virtual environments, as they both solve this particular problem, and are the industry standard because they solve many problems.

### Simple process:

1. install python-virtualenv :

   $>sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv  # on Ubuntu
2. create a virtual-env against the Python you want, and activate it

   $> virtualenv -p /usr/bin/pythonX ve

   $> source ve/bin/activate
3. install django into this virtual-env

   $> pip install django

...

PROFIT!

Answer (score 2):

You can mention explicitly the `python` version while installing.

First  download the source from [django website.](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)

Now extract it to any location and open the terminal and go to the location into the folder. There must be a file named `setup.py` that is the installation file.Now type:

For `Python 3.2`

```
python3.2 setup.py install
```

For `Python 2.7`

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```